# codeignte route not workng afer upgrading codeignite 3.1.11 and php 7.1

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-7

i have a codeignte project i old  version i upgrade my project in  codeigite 3.1.11 and php 7.1 every thing is work fine but  my custom route not working. but my old project this route working fine. please check my code and give me some solution.I am try so may change in my htacess and rout. I a use config uri_protocol is REQUEST_URI
here is my **roue.php**

```
    $url    =   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url    =   explode('/',$url);

$url=end($url);

$secondlasturl  = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$controller     =   $secondlasturl[1];
$second_url =   $secondlasturl[2];
if(isset($secondlasturl[3])){
    $third_url  =   $secondlasturl[3];
}else{
    $third_url='';
}


//$min=explode('-',$second_url1);

$con    = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

if($url!=''){

    $sql    =   'select CompanyID, shorturl, BusinessType from lxn_companies where shorturl ="'.$url.'"';

    $res=mysqli_query($con, $sql);


    if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {

        $row    =  mysqli_fetch_row($res);
        //print_r($row);
        $type   =   $row[2];
        if($type=='Exporters')
        {
            $userlink   =   'ExporterDetail/'.$row[0];

        }
        else
        {
            $userlink   =   'ImporterDetail/'.$row[0];
        }

        $route['(:any)'] = "user/".$userlink."";
    }
    else
    {


        $sql    =   'select CompanyID, sef_url, BusinessType from lxn_companies where sef_url ="'.$url.'"';
        $res=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
        {
            $row    =  mysqli_fetch_row($res);
            //print_r($row);
            $type   =   $row[2];
            if($type=='Exporters')
            {
                $userlink   =   'ExporterDetail/'.$row[0];

            }
            else
            {
                $userlink   =   'ImporterDetail/'.$row[0];
            }

            $route['(.*)'] = "user/".$userlink."";
        }

    }
}
```

I am using this htacess code for my project.

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine on
    
        RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
    # Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
    <IfModule mime_module>
      AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your "Working version" also running on PHP 7.1? mysql_xxxx has been removed since PHP 7 which might be why it's not working. You should also check your error logs on your server.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw can you explain that the query is work the i check the query  result

Comment: Read this - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @TimBrownlaw  yes I upgraade mysql query but not working

Comment: @MinhazurRahaman - You need to check your IF statements. In the last one you do it correctly using mysqlI_num_rows. In the first one you actually read the row. So you are trying to do the same thing, two different ways. Why don't you use the inbuilt CI functions like $this->db->query($sql) and you would never have had this problem to begin with.

Comment: @MinhazurRahaman is the code you provided the full roue.php file? And where does it live and how are you calling it in your code?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw  yes I check my if statement it ok and come data  near $route['(.*)']. and  $route['(.*)'] = "user/".$userlink.""; but show 404 error

Comment: @MinhazurRahaman I disbelieve! You are using if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) which reads the Row so you've lost the first result and then you attempt to read the next row? That is nothing like the 2nd section where you are testing for num_rows.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your existing code, I've come up with this for you to try.

Yes, it is using mysqli and not PDO (yet) so everyone else, please don't cremate me for this.

**The Setup:** ( You need to provide this kind of information in future questions if required.)

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lxn_companies;
    CREATE TABLE lxn_companies (
      CompanyID INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      BusinessType VARCHAR(48),
      shorturl VARCHAR(128),
      sef_url VARCHAR(128)
    );

INSERT INTO lxn_companies
(CompanyID, BusinessType, shorturl, sef_url) values
(1,'Exporters','CompanyID1_short_url',''),
(2,'Importers','CompanyID2_short_url',''),
(3,'Exporters','','CompanyID3_sef_url'),
(4,'Importers','','CompanyID4_sef_url');
```

**The "roue.php" file**

Where you see code repeating (as your code does) its begging to be refactored.

I've not got time right now to explain everything here, but have a read over it.

Main points - Used mysqli_fetch_assoc (association) when reading the DB Row Columns (fields) so use the names (more readable) and not numeric indexes (hard to understand).

```
$url_array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = end($url_array);
// The Following 3 variables are not used in this code.
//$controller = isset($url_array[1]) ? $url_array[1] : '';
//$second_url = isset($url_array[2]) ? $url_array[2] : '';
//$third_url = isset($url_array[3]) ? $url_array[3] : '';

if ($url != '') {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
    // Look for entries with either shorturl or sef_url.
    // A Row cannot have both shorturl and sef_url
    $sql = "SELECT 
                CompanyID,
                BusinessType
             FROM lxn_companies 
             WHERE shorturl = '{$url}'
             OR sef_url = '{$url}'
            ";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($res && mysqli_num_rows($res)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if ($row['BusinessType'] == 'Exporters') {
            $userlink = 'ExporterDetail/';
        } else {
            $userlink = 'ImporterDetail/';
        }
        $route['(.*)'] = "user/" . $userlink . $row['CompanyID'];
    }
}

// Debug Stuff
echo '<pre>';
echo 'LINE: ' . __LINE__ . ' Module ' . __CLASS__ . '<br>';
var_dump($route);
echo '</pre>';
exit('Stop here to inspect the final routes');
```

I "included" this file inside the application/config/routes.php.

**Things to fix:**
Replace mysqli with PDO